# Zipped folder is corrupted when using a buffer as the output

Tags: go, zip

I'm trying to write the zip file to a buffer instead of a file to eventually pass it to the http response. Below is the code to simulate that.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    data, err := zipit("myfolder")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ioutil.WriteFile("output.zip", data, os.ModePerm)
}

func zipit(source string) ([]byte, error) {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    archive := zip.NewWriter(buf)
    defer archive.Close()
    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }
    filepath.Walk(source, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Deflate
        }

        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })
    return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

However the output of this zip process is corrupted. If I use a file instead of a buffer it works thought.

```
zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer zipfile.Close()

archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
defer archive.Close()
```

Both os.File and bytes.Buffer implements io.Writer interface and eligible to be passed as a writer to zip.NewWrite() method.

Any direction to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the buffer before you've closed the zip.Writer, so any final data is needs to flush to the buffer has gotten lost. You should remove the `defer archive.Close()` and instead close the archive before getting the bytes out of the buffer. e.g.

```
    err = archive.Close()
    return buf.Bytes(), err
```

It works in your file case because you defer closing the file. The defer's will be applied last in first out, so the archive gets closed before the file is closed.